# React Frontend and Apollo Graphql Server deployment

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, graphql, apollo

i have build an application with a React Frontend and ApolloServer Backend. I want to deploy both to a ubuntu server via Docker (two Containers). The Frontend is deployed via Nginx and the backend via pm2 docker images. My question is whether i should make the Server publicly available for Client graphql requests? Or is there an other way to proxy the frontend request through nginx and keeping the backend "privat"? If this is possible i could use cor to enforce some more security (only accepting localhost requests). 
Thanks a lot for your advises

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit what problem you're running into?  Putting an nginx proxy in front of your server is pretty common, and you can have it do some security enforcement and share a domain for CORS purposes.

Comment: I initially wanted to know whether it was possible to have react contact the Backend directly without exposing an API endpoint (it is not). If I had a cors policy enforced by the Backend Server API it would not be very useful because the API will get hits from a lot of different domains anyway non ? I am sorry for the question not being clear I am still learning... Thanks a lot